# using dropdown list value in a URL

Tags: asp.net, ssrs-2008

I have a page that the user chooses a date range, a name, and a Form type (A, B, E, T). On the basis of that, I populate a grid with the results and hyperlink a report number. When the user clicks the report number, a report is displayed. How can I insert the drop down list selected value into the URL to get the proper report based upon the report type the user chooses? If the user chooses Form A, the URL for SSRS should call the forma report from SSRS, and so on.

**Markup**

```
<body>
 <link href="StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
<center><h1>Custom Reporting<br />
    Pick a date range, an Inspector, and the type of inspection to list:</h1>
    <p>Note - Date range is the dates of inspection, not dates of data input</p><br />
    Start date: <asp:TextBox ID="stdt" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="stdt" ErrorMessage="mm/dd/yyyy" ValidationExpression="^((0?[13578]|10|12)(-|\/)(([1-9])|(0[1-9])|([12])([0-9]?)|(3[01]?))(-|\/)((19)([2-9])(\d{1})|(20)([01])(\d{1})|([8901])(\d{1}))|(0?[2469]|11)(-|\/)(([1-9])|(0[1-9])|([12])([0-9]?)|(3[0]?))(-|\/)((19)([2-9])(\d{1})|(20)([01])(\d{1})|([8901])(\d{1})))$" Display="Dynamic"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator> End date: <asp:TextBox ID="enddt" runat="server">
        </asp:TextBox>
    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="enddt" ErrorMessage="mm/dd/yyyy" ValidationExpression="^((0?[13578]|10|12)(-|\/)(([1-9])|(0[1-9])|([12])([0-9]?)|(3[01]?))(-|\/)((19)([2-9])(\d{1})|(20)([01])(\d{1})|([8901])(\d{1}))|(0?[2469]|11)(-|\/)(([1-9])|(0[1-9])|([12])([0-9]?)|(3[0]?))(-|\/)((19)([2-9])(\d{1})|(20)([01])(\d{1})|([8901])(\d{1})))$" Display="Dynamic"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator> Inspector: <asp:DropDownList ID="DDLInsp" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="Name">
    </asp:DropDownList> 
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ESDFormsConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [Name] FROM [Inspectors] ORDER BY [Name]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
    Inspection Type: <asp:DropDownList ID="DDLType" runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem>Form A</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Form B</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Form E</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Form T</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Selected="True">Pick One</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="btnFind" runat="server" Text="Find Reports" />
    <br />
    </center>
</div>
    <br />
<center>
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" EmptyDataText="No records found" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#999999" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" GridLines="Vertical">
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#DCDCDC" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="enddt" HeaderText ="Date" DataFormatString="{0:d}" />
            <asp:HyperlinkField HeaderText="Report Number" DataTextField="rptnum" DataNavigateURLFields="rptnum" DataNavigateurlformatstring="http://servername/ReportServer?/esdforms/THE REPORT TITLE SHOULD GO HERE&rs:Command=Render&rc:Parameters=False&rptnum={0}" />
        </Columns>
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" ForeColor="Black" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#000084" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#999999" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#EEEEEE" ForeColor="Black" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#008A8C" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1F1F1" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#0000A9" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#CAC9C9" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#000065" />
    </asp:GridView></center>

</form>
```

Comment: bad tagging..not vb.net